# Android: My webview app doesn't have permissions to access file and photos

Tags: android, permissions

I'm sorry for my knowledge, i hope you can help me. I have read this tutorial:
[convert website to android app with android studio](https://www.touchstoneinfotech.com/convert-website-into-android-app/) and converted successfully my website to android app.

My website has the OCR button (using tesseract.js for text regconition), this button works fine if i access my website on browser (safari/chrome, ...).

But it doesn't work on my Webview App. I press this button, nothing happens. I think the reason is permission or other causes.

Can you help me to view the code on the above link, are there any additional codes needed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the necessary permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml file and handle the permission request in your activity or fragment code.

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mywebviewapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <!-- ... -->

</manifest>
```

Handle the permission request in your activity or fragment code. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 100;

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);

        // Check if the app has storage permission
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Request the storage permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            // Load the webview
            mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_STORAGE_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Load the webview
                mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");
            } else {
                // Permission denied, handle the error
                Toast.makeText(this, "Storage permission required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```